# React/NextJs - How to get Snap-Scroll Position?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

[My Demo](https://next-js-quiz-dummy.vercel.app/) | [Source Code](https://github.com/onurz24/NextJS-Quiz-Dummy)

I have a "Question Container" with the CSS (Tailwind) Properties :

`snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-auto`

And inside that "Question Container" there live 4 dynamically rendered "Question"s with Properties

`snap-center 100% Height/Width`.

Like Screens you scroll down to the next question.

Now the problem is that i have no clue how i can read on which Question i am and then of course how to scroll to the next/previous when i'm clicking on that "ArrowUp" "ArrowDown" Button or the "OK" Button.

Window.scrollBy doesnt work either because obviously it lives in a container that is scrollable.

And i additionaly i want to prevent scrolling before a answer is selected.

Can anyone help me what i need to add in the project to make it working ?
Then i can continue doing the rest of the logic by myself

I did try Googleing and asking on Reddit, Gutefrage.net, ChatGPT.
Result => No Similar Case Found and got no Help on other Forums.

I expect maybe a little Code Snippet what i need to add or ideal a github pull request from a more expierenced User.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.